# from django.shortcuts import reverse ImportError: cannot import name 'reverse'

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error:

```
 Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f78dfe090d0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/onehyr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/onehyr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/webapps/onehyr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/webapps/onehyr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/webapps/onehyr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/onehyr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/webapps/onehyr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/webapps/onehyr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/webapps/onehyr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/webapps/onehyr/ladislist/blog/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.shortcuts import reverse
ImportError: cannot import name 'reverse'
```

Here are my imports in model.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.utils import timezone, html
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
```

Django version is 2.0.1

It was all working perfectly until I installed django-grappelli. Now even after uninstalling it, I still face the same issue. Like my entire django just went haywire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the issue. I also installed django-tinymce-4 via pip which downgraded my django installation to 1.9.2 during installation. I had to uninstall and reinstall django.

I advice people to stay clear of that for now unless your `django --version <= 1.9.2`